# How to modify incorrect date in a SQL Server database column in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have a column in my SQL Server database of `nvarchar` datatype, and I store dates with `####/##/##` format in it. With my mistake some of dates store with `##/##/####` format.

How can I modify all dates in my database to format `####,##,##`?

Example: `01/01/2016` to `2016/01/01`

Comment: Is the bad data mm/dd/yyyy (American) or dd/mm/yyyy (Nearly everywhere else)

Comment: Their is a datatype called `date` for saving dates then why are you trying to compromise with `nvarchar`

Comment: If you're in the mood to fix the data, why not do it right and switch to using a `datetime2` or `date` column?

Comment: Don't store dates in your database as strings. Use the proper data type. Only convert to a string at the point where you actually need to display to the user.

Comment: The problem is the field type, not the format. You should store dates in date-typed fields (date, datetime etc). Fix your table schema, not your data

Comment: take the value of this string and the key of this entry. check if 3rd Char is `/`.If so substring it into `string_yyyy`, `string_mm`and `string_dd` create a new type/string/date and write it back (update on key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CONVERT` function. Write simple SQL query:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
-- get Date from nvarchar and format to yyyy/mm/dd
SET DateColumn = CONVERT(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATE, DateColumn, 103), 111)
-- only in rows that can be parsed from dd/mm/yyyy format
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DateColumn, 103) IS NOT NULL
```

`103` - `dd/mm/yyyy` format. `111` - `yyyy/mm/dd` format. [check this article](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

But actually you really should **store your dates in `DATE` type column not in `NVARCHAR`**.

Comment: i get this error : 'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @R.F.V what version of MS SQL do you use? It's 2012 version function

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60

Comment: @R.F.V strange... I tested on my 2012 db - woks fine